# I want to build a voice controlled robot please tell how should I proceed

Tags: robotics

I want to make a robot that follows my voice commands. So what sort of micro controller should I use? Should I go with Arduino or Should I use A Raspberry Pi. And also please tell me what language should I code in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need two things here: a processor and a controller. You need a processor that can process data, do computations, run code etc. You need a controller for I/O. Raspberry pi has a strong(compared to Arduino) processor but the 40 GPIO pins are all digital i.e. you won't be able to use it alone for analog I/O (controlling the speed of the vehicle, reading sensor data etc.). Arduino on the other hand can handle both analog and digital I/O, but it has very low processing power. Generally people use both of them together. You will also need motor drivers, battery management circuit etc. Coming to the code, it should have two parts: one that processes your voice and understands the command, one that takes the command and tells the robot what to do.  Both could be done in C. For speech synthesis, you could use existing APIs and for controlling the robot, you can use Arduino libraries. I hope this answers your question.